# Using selenium , I was trying to move from one element to another using x path in siblings

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browser-automation, testautomationfx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao4L4.jpg)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\5558\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe" );
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in"); //url in the browser
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-xshop']/a[1]/following-sibling::a[2]")).click();
}
}
```

Need to hit mobiles but it is hitting fashion , Please help in correcting

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-xshop']/a[1]/following-sibling::a[2]")).click();
```

Use this locator:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mobile-phones')]")).click();
```

You should also add an explicit wait there so your code should be something like this:

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\5558\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe" );
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in"); //url in the browser
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mobile-phones')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mobile-phones')]")).click();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `css_selector`  :

```
a[href^='/mobile-phones/b/']
```

use it like below :

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href^='/mobile-phones/b/']")).click();
```

**xpath** would be :

```
//a[contains(@href, '/mobile-phones/b/')]
```

use it like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/mobile-phones/b/')]")).click();
```